# Ошибка в построении класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
from Person import *
class House:
def __init__(self,adress = "None",listOfResidents=["none"]):
    self.__adress = adress
    self.__listOfResidents = listOfResidents

def setAdress(self,adress):
    self.__adress = adress

def adress(self):
    return self.__adress

def settlePerson(self,person):
    if isinstance(person,Person):
        self.__listOfResidents.append(person)
        person.setAdress(self.__adress)

def evictPerson(self,person):
    self.__listOfResidents.remove(person)
    person.setAdress("None")

def showHouse(self):
    print("Adress is: ", self.__adress)
    i = 1;
    for p in self.__listOfResidents:

        if isinstance(p,Person):
            print(str(i) + " " + p.name())
            i += 1;


pers1 = Person("Alex",20,"Kingstreet 1")
pers2 = Person("John", 45, "Spasskaya 5")
house1 = House("Adress-7")
house1.settlePerson(pers1)
house1.settlePerson(pers2)

house1.showHouse()
prog1 = Programmer("BB King", 30,"Spain",3)
house2 = House("Adressbh")
house2.settlePerson(prog1)
```

В первом доме у меня два человека и должно быть, но во втором, программист и те два, с первого дома. Подскажите, как исправить? Видимо у меня добавляется в один и тот же дом

Comment: У вас список `listOfResidents` общий для всех домов

Comment: @andreymal подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?)

Comment: Вынести за класс и после возврата обнулять.

Comment: @And буду очень благодарен, если конкретно напиши как реализовать, а то не могу понять((